# restrict access to login symfony depending on the role

Tags: symfony

I am using symfony for the first time and I want to restrict access to /login for logged users depending on their role

this is my securityController

```
class SecurityController extends BaseController
{
    public function renderLogin(array $data)
    {
        if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('covoiturage_acceuil');
        } else if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_home');
        }

        return $this->render("CovoiturageBundle:User:login.html.twig", $data);
    }
}
```

When I'm logged as a user all is good but when I'm logged as an admin I'm redirected to the route (`covoiturage_acceuil`)

Answer (score 3):

That's because a Admin has also a ROLE_USER. You can change the order of your condition to solve the issue :

```
public function renderLogin(array $data)
{
    if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_home');} //verify first that it's not an admin

    else if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('covoiturage_acceuil');}

    return $this->render("CovoiturageBundle:User:login.html.twig", $data);
}
```

Also, in french, 'accueil' not 'acceuil' ;)

Comment: merci !! et pour "accueil" c'étais une faute de frappe pas plus ;)